# Google Webmaster Tools Index Status is 0

Tags: google, google-search-console, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Statistics show all entries of my wordpress blog have been tracked, but none have been indexed.

I thought it would be just a matter of indexing delay, but it has been 3 weeks already, and I can find the entries on google when I query the entry name, (e.g "relaxacion.com musica para dormir bebes" shows at the bottom of search results first page)

Is there any problem with my wordpress setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your site is indexed**

Your site is indexed, use `site:yourdomain.com` in Google and your see the indexed pages. Test here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.relaxacion.com

**WordPress is not being blocked**

The only way WordPress would be blocking your pages being blocked is using robots.txt and noindex, I've investigated and none of these seem to be an issue.

**Don't always trust Google Webmaster Tools**

Google Webmaster Tools is often incorrect or outdated... The fact it says 0 indexed obviously is wrong because your site can be found in Google.

**Ranking issue**

What your describing is ranking issues, the only problem you have is that your content is extremely lite... You have embedd of videos on the page with no text. Google will not favour these pages, give the videos descriptions and try to keep pages above 300 words if you want good rankings.

Comment: _Don't always trust Google Webmaster Tools_ - "indexed pages" is only updated after more than four weeks or so

Answer (score 0):

Don't pay attention in number of indexed pages in Google Webmaster Tools, it's not reliable all the time. This number will be updated later.

Your site is correctly indexed; the proof [here](http://www.google.com/search?ix=aca&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3arelaxacion.com) (44 indexed pages).

Moreover, I have analyzed source code of your home page and all is fine.

Comment: Damn you! you beat me too it ;)

Comment: Sorry buddy... :)